# Can't add new attributes to the HTTP headers along with the existing request headers

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, api-gateway

My goal is to add `caller` and `request-id` to the HTTP headers.
However, I can't seem to get it right. Those are not added along with the existing headers.

What's wrong?

```
{
"headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end

    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add it to your Integration Request headers? If so, this is not configured in the body mapping template. The mapping template is just for configuring the payload to the integration.

You should add a header named `caller` (or whatever you want) and set the mapping expression value to `$context.identity.caller`. Then API GW will send that value in the header to your integration.